# Connection must be valid and open ( again )

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, rows

I'm having the error "Connection must be valid and open again, when I changed my sql query code. Can anyone help?? (edit) In form1 I have connected to database, in form2 I'm trying to add queries.

```
//IN Class1.cs
public void test(string query, string name)
{
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.CommandText = @query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name);
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Reader[0]);
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
//IN Form2.cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    name = textBox1.Text;
    var obj = new Class1();
    obj.test(@"SELECT * FROM players WHERE name = ?Name;", name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the connection is being disposed of (or possible not even opened at all!)

Ideally I'd change that to use a unit-of-work approach, and also wrap your instances in using blocks to ensure they are correctly disposed of:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("connection-string"))
{
  using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
  {
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", name);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, what's the purpose of calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after you've already used `ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: It was opened in FORM1, the code I wrote above is from FORM2.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when I opened a connection in one class and tried to use it in a different class/form. It is totally okay to more than one connection open at a time, so make a new MySqlConnection instance for every class, and open and close it inside that class.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
cmd.Open();
```

... BEFORE ExecuteNonQuery()

:) I hope this helps, please advise if you're still having troubles.

Also, for the time being, try removing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery, as I think it may be connecting twice, hence the error "Connection must be valid and open". It must not be "open" because you're already connected using ExecuteReader().

Comment: cmd.Open() didn't work, its not even listed at all. (if you're talking about the connection.Open() I can tell you it's already opened in FORM1, the first window.